# Binomial distribution from a measure-theoretic point of view

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am trying to make a connection between "naive" probability and Probability theory (in other words, undergraduate to graduate probability). That why of was thinking of the Binomial distribution (please correct me if I am wrong):

$\triangle$ "Naive" probabilistic approach.

take an experiment with two possible outcomes, success (:1) with probability $p$, failure (:0) with probability $1-p$. We repeat this experiment $n$ independent times. Set X to be the number of successes in these $n$ repetitions. So $X\sim Binom(n,p)$ and $\displaystyle P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},~k=0,1,2,\ldots,n.$

$\Box$ Measuretheoretic approach.

1) The space of outcomes $\Omega$: it seems that this is fairly easy, it is $\{0,1\}^n$.

2) The $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F}$: well, this is the $\sigma-$algebra generated by the class of all sets of the form $A_1\times \ldots \times A_n$, where $A_1,\ldots, A_n \subseteq\{0,1\}$  (QUESTION: what does the case $A_1=\emptyset$ represent in the real experiment described above?)

3) Probability measure $P$: This is $P(A_1\times \ldots \times A_n)=p(A_1)\ldots p(A_n)$, where $p(\{0\})=1-p,~p(\{1\})=p,$ extended on $\mathcal{F}$ according to Caratheodory's extension theorem.

4) Random variable $X$: We define $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: X((\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n))=\omega_1+\ldots+\omega_n =$ the number of successes. Now, $X$ is a random variable since for $k$ in $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ the set $\{X=k\}$ constists of all $\binom{n}{k}$ unions of the sets of the n-tuples of $\{0\}'$s and $\{1\}'$s, such that $\{1\}'$s appear $k$ times exactly. So, $\{X=k\}\in \mathcal{F}$ for all $k$.

5) Probability of the events of $X$: each n-tuple that appears in the above union has probability $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, by the definition of $P$ and since there are $\binom{n}{k}$ of them we get the known formula for $P(X=k).$

Is the setting correct?

Thanks a lot for any comments.

ps. It seems to me very interesting that the whole thing actually refers to the outcomes $\omega\in \Omega,$ instead of $X$ itself (although  in an undergraduate probability course somebody might not even hear about a space $\Omega$ called the space of outcomes and all it's relatives).

Comment: The space of outcomes is not correct.  Stating that it is $\{0,1\}^n$ implies that the order of outcomes matters.  However, a binomial distribution does not care about the order.  Therefore, the space of outcomes should simply be $\{0,1,\dots,n \}$

Comment: @Paul thanks. I think the outcomes appear as $n-$tuples of the form $(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)$ where $\omega_i\in \{0,1\}$. How come our function $X$ does not care about the order since it counts $\{0\}\times \{1\}\times \{0\}\times\ldots\{0\}$ and $\{1\}\times \{0\}\times \{0\}\times\ldots\{0\}$ as two different outcomes (of 1 success, of course)?

Comment: tl;dr. http://www.amazon.com/Measure-Theory-Probability-Wadsworth-Mathematics/dp/0817638849 is a great "bridge" book.

Comment: The binomial distribution treats those 2 the same.  What you are describing is a different distribution.

Comment: @Paul "Outcomes" does not refer to "outcomes of the random variable X." A better translation is "set of possible states the universe can be in". X is a function defined on this universe. Equipped with the measure OP defined on $\Omega$, $X$ is binomially distributed, which was OP's goal.

Comment: @A.S. thanks for mentioning!